# Unexpected result regarding lambdas and concurrency

Tags: java, lambda, concurrency

I have been looking in to the `volatile` keyword, and how it can be used to manipulate the way memory is stored and accessed from the CPU cache. I am using a simple test program to explore how storing 2 variables, each being accessed by a concurrently executing thread, on different cache lines improves read/write speed. Obviously, this method would never be used in the real world, however, I found the following program very useful in demonstrating and understanding how data is stored in the CPU cache, albeit very crudely:

```
public class Volatile {

private volatile int a = 0;
private long dummy1 = 0;
private long dummy2 = 0;
private long dummy3 = 0;
private long dummy4 = 0;
private volatile int b = 0;

private static long lastA;
private static long lastB;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Volatile instance = new Volatile();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lastA = System.nanoTime();
                while(true){
                    instance.a++;
                    if(instance.a % 100_000_000 == 0){
                        System.out.println("A: " + (System.nanoTime() - lastA) / 1000000 + "ms");
                        lastA = System.nanoTime();
                        instance.a = 0;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lastB = System.nanoTime();
                while(true){
                    instance.b++;
                    if(instance.b % 100_000_000 == 0){
                        System.out.println("B: " + (System.nanoTime() - lastB) / 1000000 + "ms");
                        lastB = System.nanoTime();
                        instance.b = 0;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }).start();

}
```

}

Here, the code is padding dummy variables between `a` and `b` such that they will be stored on separate cache lines, and the 2 threads accessing them will not clash. The results produced by this program are as expected, and the time taken to increment each variable to `100_000_000` is approximately 600-700 ms for my CPU. Removing the dummy variables increases this time to approximately 3000-4000 ms.

This is where I encounter some behavior I do not understand.

I replicated the code exactly in a separate class, however, I replaced the anonymous inner class passed into the thread creation with a lambda expression:

i.e

```
final VolatileLambda instance = new VolatileLambda();
        new Thread(() -> {
                lastA = System.nanoTime();
                while(true){
```

and

```
        new Thread(() -> {
                lastB = System.nanoTime();
                while(true){
```

When I ran this second program with lambdas, I encountered different results to the first program in that the padding variables were no longer sufficient to separate `a` and `b` on to separate cache lines, causing the threads to clash and again producing an output of 3000-4000 ms. This was solved by declaring an extra single dummy byte variable after the dummy longs:

```
private long dummy4 = 0;
private byte dummy5 = 0;
private volatile int b = 0;
```

The output after declaring this extra byte was then, once again, approximately 600-700 ms.

I have replicated this comparison numerous times on different systems and, strangely, this produces no consistent outcome. Sometimes, using lambdas over anonymous inner classes has no effect on the output, sometimes it does. Even attempting the same comparison on the same system at different times did not always produce the same results.

I'm at a loss trying to explain this behavior, and would greatly appreciate any help. Feel free to ask for clarification on anything, as I probably did not explain this very well.

Thanks!